# SEO-friendly links with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using Ajax jQuery to load the data as below:

```
<div id=result></div>
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/co.aspx/getdata",
    success: function(r) {
      var dt = JSON.parse(r.d);
      var str='<a href='+ dt[i].Link+'>'+ dt[i].Name +'</a><br/>';
      $("#result").html(str);
    }
  }):
```

But these links are not going to list in Google as they're not generated by any sitemap generator.

How can I make it SEO friendly?

Comment: variable 'i' is not defined in the success function... Is there an error in the browser console ?

Comment: it is just example it is working fine there is looop before it.. issue is this links are not noticeable in sitemap generator and google

Answer (score 1):

Follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

1. Build a website that works without JS
2. Enhance it with JS
3. Use [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to update the address with the non-Ajax address for a page when you use Ajax to manipulate the view